# Use echo to send input from one terminal to another

Tags: c++, c, linux, terminal

I try to send an input with for example `echo "some_input" | write /dev/pts/0` or `echo "some_input" > /dev/pts/0` from a terminal `/dev/pts/1` to another `/dev/pts/0`

In the second terminal, a program is running, for example :

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

int main()
{
    while(std::cin){
        std::string s;

        std::cin >> s;
        std::cout << s;
    }
}
```

I am having some difficulty with it. I can write the input (using echo) to the other terminal but the input is not validated and the program gets stuck in `std::cin`.
I would like to write an input and validate it as if I press enter

How could I do this?

Comment: You're writing to the display section of the other terminal; you're not writing to the input section.  Further, it isn't clear that you can simply write in such a way that the other terminal treats what you write as input.  I'm not aware of a POSIX mechanism for doing so.  All else apart, such a mechanism would be a major security flaw.

Comment: idk if it would be a "major security flaw" any more than being able to write to the display is. You have to be logged in as the same user.

Comment: You can't "send input" to a terminal -- it makes no sense.  You can only send data to a terminal (which it will display), or read data from a terminal (which it sends to you, normally from its keyboard).  If you have a pseudo-terminal, you can ask it to "simulate terminal input", which may be what you want.

Comment: Your question is C++ specific.  Please, don't tag it as `C`.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can come to what I think you're trying to do is by using the TIOCSTI ioctl.  A small C program like:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main(int ac, char **av) {
    if (ac != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <terminal>\n", av[0]);
        exit(1); }
    int term = open(av[1], O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (term < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s: %s\n", av[1], strerror(errno));
        exit(1); }
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        char c = ch;
        if (ioctl(term, TIOCSTI, &c) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't simulate input on %s: %s\n", av[1], strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

will write its stdin to the input buffer of a terminal that supports that capability.  Depending on your system security setup, you may need to be root to do this.

You should then be able to pipe an `echo` command to stdin of this program and it will "push" that into the terminal's input buffer, where it will then be read by whoever is reading from the terminal, as if it came from the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I will try your piece of code otherwise I found another way to do what I want: the first program creates a file with the inputs in it, the second program (if the file exists) opens it and gets the data. So far it seems to work but I'm not sure if it's the easiest way.

Comment: If you can modify the second (receiving) program, it is much better to do so and have it open additional channels for receiving input.  A named pipe or UNIX domain socket is probably a better (more flexible) idea than a simple file.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to send an input with for example echo "some_input" | write /dev/pts/0 or echo "some_input" > /dev/pts/0 from a terminal /dev/pts/1 to another /dev/pts/0

In general, you cannot make a program that is already running in a POSIX tty to accept your input through its current standard input.

The problem is that the program is waiting for input on the device associated to it's standard input and so, only the input from that tty is given to the program.  If you try to write to `/proc/<pid_of_program>/fd/0`  you will write to the same tty device that is associated with the input of the program, but you are writing to the device and this will make the text to appear as output through that device (not as input to the program)

You can specify a redirection to a program that you start, and you can make your program to open a file descriptor, but to get in the middle and insert input to an already launched program is not possible.

Of course, you can run a program in another tty, specifying that it should read from a different place than the controlling tty, this is done in the shell by using the operator `<`  just start the program telling that the standard input will come (e.g. from `/dev/zero`) and your program will start and show a lot of null bytes, e.g.:

```
$ hd </dev/zero
00000000 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
*
^C938ebd10
```

(you need to interrupt it with Ctrl-C)

Anyway, it is not clear what do you want to do exactly, this seems an instance of an XY problem. If you can extend your question to show what do you intend exactly, probably more help can be given.